# phonegap Android App Pinch Zoom specific page

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova, zooming

i am building a magazine android app for a client using Phonegap and eclipse. The problem comes when i am in a magazine.html page and i want users to zoom the magazine pages (saved as jpeg). I tried setting the meta tags to this but it didnt work.

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"

I have also use the android zoom code it works but the problem is it allow zooming everything and when you zoom only text will be affected and not images. Also using this code i cant e zchoose whether i want to zoom a specific page only (magazine.html).

```
public class MyApp extends CordovaActivity
```

{

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

   settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);


}
```

}

I have been trying to solve this for days, any help from you guys will really appreciate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this PinchZoom.js.

```
    new PinchZoom($('#your-element'), options);


    tapZoomFactor:      The zoom factor a double tap zooms to. (default 2)
    zoomOutFactor:      Resizes to original size when zoom factor is below the configured value. (default 1.3)
    animationDuration:  The animation duration in milliseconds. (default 300)
    maxZoom:            The maximum zoom factor. (default 4)
    minZoom:            The minimum zoom factor. (default 0.5)
```

http://rtp-ch.github.io/pinchzoom/demo/swipe.html

http://rtp-ch.github.io/pinchzoom/

Comment: thanks amit for your answer,i used iscroll.js and hammer.js to accomplish this but it didnt work. before i tried pinchzoom,i would like to ask if their is a way to solve this without using any javascript library, either playing with meta tags or mainActivity java file?